# Inline-blocks inside fixed width content overflowing

Tags: css

I have two inline-blocks of fixed content, I'm trying to display these next to each other.

They're both held within a div of `width: 1000px;`, the two inline-block divs are both `width: 400px;` and `width: 600px;` respectively.

The two divs however don't display inline, the second div collapses underneath the first, if I drop the width of the second to `width: 550px;` they both display inline, my question being:

How come two divisions that have a combined width of `1000px` can't both fit inside a container that has a width of `1000px;`?

Fiddle below.

```
<div class="layout">
  <div class="width">
    <div class="area left">

    </div>
    <div class="area right">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.layout {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 250px;
  padding-right: 250px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.layout .area.left, .layout .area.right {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 250px;
}

.layout .area.left {
  width: 400px;
  background: green;
}

.layout .area.right {
  width: 600px;
  background: blue;
}

.width {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4asw47yg/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Comment: and updated fiddle with the fix - https://jsfiddle.net/4asw47yg/1/ is that it?

Answer (score 3):

It's because the browser is accounting for the space **between** the two `.area` `<div>` elements. If you simply remove the space (and make *no* other changes), it will work - like this:

```
<div class="layout">
  <div class="width">
    <div class="area left">

    </div><div class="area right">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here's an updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4asw47yg/2/) showing the results.

To be clear: the reason you're seeing this is the `display: inline-block`. Compare, and you'll notice the vertical space difference between [with it (gap)](https://jsfiddle.net/4asw47yg/3/) and [without it (no gap)](https://jsfiddle.net/4asw47yg/4/). I was going to try and explain this further, but it looks like [there's an excellent write-up already here](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

Comment: I understand why it's occurring, but ugh - that just makes my html ugly ^^. Cheers anyway dude, I'll get this done.

Answer (score 1):

You can either remove the `display: inline-block` and float the elements, or add a margin of -4px to the DIVs. If you have access to the HTML you can remove the white space around the two DIVs and it will display properly.

```
<div class="layout">
  <div class="width">
    <div class="area left"></div><div class="area right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Read this article to learn more about it: http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/

Comment: A good idea for keeping the line breaks in the source code but still having no spaces is using line break HTML comments: `<div></div><!--`, line break, `--><div></div>`, etc.

Comment: An other alternative is to set font-size of parent to 0, forcing to set it back to a readable value for child divs. Chris Coyier addresses this specific issue in [this article](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)